# Why menu items are not at the right of the div?

Tags: css

I want to have a menu that has a logo at left and the menu items at right, Im using flexbox for this but its not working. The menu items are stick to the logo. Do you know where is  the issue?

This is the html:

```
<div class="container">
  <header class="Header content">
    <h1 class="title"><a href="">LOGO</a></h1>
    <ul class="main_nav">
      <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </header>
</div>
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/adwkkvt6/

css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  width: 94%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.Header, .main_nav{
  display: flex;
}

.title a{
  color:green;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}

.main_nav li{

  padding: 0 15px;

}

.main_nav{
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;

}

.main_nav a{
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  color:gray;
}
```

Comment: Without flex, you can give float and fix it. https://jsfiddle.net/adwkkvt6/2/

Comment: I explain my answer  for bettet undersanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this

```
.title{
  flex:1 0 0;
}
```

title is a child so you have to give space to how mach occupy the parent div so use `flex:1 0 0` to get space for logo.

`flex:1 0 0` is -

```
flex-grow:1;
flex-shrink:0;
flex-basis:0;
```

More info about flex [visit](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

**[Updated fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/adwkkvt6/4/)**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  width: 94%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.Header,
.main_nav {
  display: flex;
}

.title {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

.title a {
  color: green;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}

.main_nav li {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.main_nav {
  background-color: red;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.main_nav a {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="Header content">
    <h1 class="title"><a href="">LOGO</a></h1>
    <ul class="main_nav">
      <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works. But so flex-grow 1 gets space for the logo, but how the menu goes to the right?

Comment: inspect the logo div i assigned only `flex-grow` for it not your navigation so it takes all the width as much as it can take. so your logo div pushed navigation to the right. if you assign `flex-grow` to navigation it will take 50% of your parent div and rest 50% will take logo div.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `<div class="clear"></div>`, you can use `justify-content: space-between` like that

```
.Header, .main_nav{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if you can check this "https://jsfiddle.net/adwkkvt6/5/" the menu items are not at the right of the .content div. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the positioning of the flexbox items:

```
.Header, .main_nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

the default value of `justify-content` is `flex-start` which pushes each item to the left of the flexbox.